# Ubuntu 16.04/14.04 + Pro-Ject DS2 Ultra external DAC doesn't work

Tags: external-soundcard

i'd like to ask for some help, at the moment i'm struggling with that, maybe someone already knows this problem and/or even got a solution for that...

i bought an external DAC (Pro-Ject DAC Box DS2 Ultra) and i'd like to use it with my computer...based on the description from the company it doesn't need any drivers on Linux-systems, kinda "plug-n-play" device...but in my case it doesn't work...no sound, nothing even the system doesn't recognize this device...after some re- and unplugging alsamixer recognizes this as an external sound card, but refuses to use because of some kind of "protocol failure"

any ideas about what could be wrong? thanks in advance!

i tried it with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32bit), Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64bit) and with Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS, resulkts are the same, no differences.

this is what i get till now:

```
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ lsusb  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b008 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB 2.0 Camera   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0951:1603 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 1GB/2GB Pen     Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0930:0508 Toshiba Corp. Integrated Bluetooth HCI    
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

---

```
ubuntu-studio@ubuntu-studio:~$ dmesg | grep -i usb  
..  
..  
..  
[ 247.431215] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci  
[ 247.550578] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2772, idProduct=0201  
[ 247.550585] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0  
[ 247.550589] usb 2-2: Product: DAC Box DS2 USB Audio 2.0  
[ 247.550593] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Project  
[ 247.727218] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio  
[ 252.898343] usb 2-2: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-110)  
[ 252.902941] usb 2-2: 1:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)  
..  
..  
..
```

Comment: @Félicien Thanks for editing my question, indeed looks way better (i had no time, i'm in my workplace)

Comment: no pb, sorry I can't help you more

Answer (score 0):

I am using a JRiver Id as my music server which initially failed to recognise the DS2 Ultra as a USB DAC. I eventually was given a firmware update by Henley Audio which after installing allowed the Id to recognise the DAC. However the DAC is unable to control the jitter when outputting 44.1 files at 44.1 via JRiver from the Id and also from my MBP. As a fix for this issue I am outputting 44.1 files at 88.2 which seems to eliminate the Jitter. Outputting 44.1 files at 44.1 via a chord Hugo 2 and Hegel HD30 show none of the jitter issues of the DS2 Ultra. Even though Project insist they cannot replicate the jitter issue my belief is that the firmware is not fully up to scratch yet with the DS2 ultra.

Answer (score -2):

home site https://www.project-audio.com/en/product/dac-box-ds2-ultra/
download firmware update utitlity
https://www.project-audio.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Pro-Ject_Firmware_Update_Utility.zip

Please uprade the firmware of your unit to minimum version 1.04 (in Downloads). After that your DAC Box DS2 ultra should work normal.

Comment: Does this Windows .exe program run in Linux and if so, how to run it?

Comment: upgrade firmware on windows only :(  ....run *.exe file in windows PC

Comment: hello alex alex, thanks for your answer! so is seems like there is no other way than upgrade this DAC via using a Windows PC and then after the firmware update it'll work wih Ubuntu flawless as it should be...sounds a bit weird, but if it works it's more than okay with me. i'll definately try it, thanks